Automatically generate PDF bookmarks for exframe problems
I'm using the exframe package to create homework sets. Is there some way to automatically create PDF bookmarks for each problem? That is, the first problem would show up as Problem 1 in the PDF bookmark, the second as Problem 2, and so on.
I'm currently doing this manually (see MWE below), but it would be good if this could be done automatically from each problem's label.
Here's how I currently do it.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exframe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Foo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pdfbookmark[0]{Problem~\ref{prob:first}}{prob:first}
\begin{problem}[label=prob:first]
   First problem.
\end{problem}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Problem~\ref{prob:snd}}{prob:snd}
\begin{problem}[label=prob:snd]
   Second problem.
\end{problem}

\end{document}


You should look at the LaTeX HOOK mechanism. Maybe it could help you there.

try \exerciseconfig{toclevelproblem}{section}

@UlrikeFischer That worked perfectly! Thanks. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

If you use \exerciseconfig{toclevelproblem}{section} the problems will be added as section to the table of contents and the bookmarks.
